# How can I get the count of the amount of rows for this result set in php?

Tags: php

I looked up how to do it and this is what I thought it said to do, however, I keep getting this error
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given

```
  <?php
 $txn_sql = " SELECT * FROM test WHERE item2 = 835587755 ";
 $order_num = mysqli_query($Connection, $txn_sql);
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($order_num);
 echo $num_rows; 
  ?>
```

Comment: Use `mysqli_*()` throughout. Don't mix APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions are from separate libraries, and the former is deprecated. You can't use `mysql_num_rows` on a `mysqli_query` result.

If you're using mysqli, you get an object back. Call the [`num_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) method on that to get the result.

```
$num_rows = $order_num->num_rows();
```

Alternatively, if you (for some reason) want to use the procedural style, you can use `mysqli_num_rows` instead.

```
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($order_num);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy, you just have to replace `mysql_num_rows` with `mysqli_num_rows`. `mysql_num_rows` can't handle a mysqli result!

So try this:

```
<?php
$txn_sql = " SELECT * FROM test WHERE item2 = 835587755 ";
$order_num = mysqli_query($Connection, $txn_sql);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($order_num);
echo $num_rows; 
?>
```